# Modified inner product

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality

Given two real valued orthogonal functions, say $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, if we define an inner product $$ \langle f,g\rangle \ = \ \int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx,$$

which we know satisfies the properties of an inner product, namely $\bf positive \ definiteness$, $\bf linearity$ in the first argument, and $\bf conjugate \ symmetry$.

Is it true that $\langle f,g\rangle = 0$ for any values of $a$ and $b$ such that $a<b$?

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal with respect to which inner product?

Comment: @marcotrevi: Isn't orthogonality universally defined? I mean, given that two functions are linearly independent, can we not deduce that their inner product must also be zero?

Comment: You said we define *an* inner product. Singular, not plural. But $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ depends on $a$ and $b$, which you seem to be allowing to vary. Which means a different inner product for each choice of $a,b$. So what's going on? Which inner product are $f,g$ orthogonal wrt? (Also conjugate symmetry isn't relevant to a *real* vector space, only a complex vector space.) And no, linearly independent vectors can easily, *easily* fail to be orthogonal. Just look at $\Bbb R^2$ to see how wrong that idea is: there are way more linearly independent pairs of vectors than orthogonal pairs.

Comment: the converse is true: orthogonality implies linear independence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually not: the choice of $a$ and $b$ is crucial. For instance, consider the orthogonal family of exponential functions $e^{inx}$. Two of these are orthogonal, that is,
$$
\langle e^{inx},e^{imx}\rangle = \int_a^b e^{i(n-m)x}\,dx=0\quad(m\neq n)
$$
if and only $b-a$ is a multiple of $2\pi$.

**Edit**: I see now that you asked for real-valued functions. Similar examples work; I chose the exponential functions because they are simple. For instance,the functions $x^n$ and $x^m$, if $n$ and $m$ are nonnegative and $n+m$ is odd, are orthogonal if and only if $b=-a$.